# How do I "stretch out" part of an image, with the whole image bending to compensate for the stretch?

Tags: image-editing, distort

For example, here is an image of a cat:

[image: cat with mouth closed]

And here is an edited image of that cat. The very small mouth part has been stretched out to be very big, and the whole image has warped and moved around the mouth to compensate for the stretch, so there are no discontinuities.

[image: cat with mouth EXTREMELY OPEN]

How can I achieve this effect a (preferably free) image editor? I primarily use Paint.NET but I'm happy to use whatever program has this capability. I've been searching for information but I haven't found anything useful because I don't know what keywords to search for. I don't know what the technical term for this operation is.

Would really appreciate any help here!

Comment: Use 'Liquify' as your search term. There are many apps that can do it. Note: You cannot achieve B directly from A with just liquify. They very probably started from an intermediate image & worked it both ways, A towards closed & B towards open.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is what I was looking for! I appreciate you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect I was looking for is called "liquify"! Thanks very much to @Tetsujin for letting me know in a comment. I found [this plugin for Paint.NET](https://github.com/bsneeze/pdn-liquify) and it does exactly what I'm looking for.